# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method (View)

Tags: android, xml, android-logcat

I have a simple app with one button on each of the three screens.
The first two buttons should send you from one intent to the next until the last button which should take a photo and print it on the third screen.
But when I added the camera function the app stopped working and now it won't even move to the second intent when I press the first "Start spil" button.

HomeActivity

```
package com.example.daniel.proto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }


    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SelectLevel.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

SelectLevelActivity

```
package com.example.daniel.proto;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;


public class SelectLevel extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_level);
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent ii = new Intent (this, QRscanner.class);
        startActivity(ii);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_select_level, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

QRscannerActivity

```
package com.example.daniel.proto;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class QRscanner extends ActionBarActivity
{

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    ImageView photoImageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qrscanner);

        Button photoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photoButton);
        photoImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);

        //Disable the button if the user doesn't have a camera
        if(!hasCamera())
            photoButton.setEnabled(false);


    }

    //Check if the user has a camera
    private boolean hasCamera()
    {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
    }

    //Launching the camera
    public void launchCamera(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //Take a picture and pass results along to onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    }

    //If you want to return the image taken
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            //Get the photo
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            photoImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Home XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Home"
    android:background="#009900">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start Spil"
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick=""
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="QuesteX"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

SelectLevel XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.daniel.proto.SelectLevel"
    android:background="#72231F">

    TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Udfordringer"
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="Click me" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

QRscanner XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.daniel.proto.QRscanner"
    android:background="#990099">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        android:id="@+id/photoButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:onClick="launchCamera" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat

```
05-15 19:41:01.902    2927-2927/com.example.daniel.proto E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.daniel.proto, PID: 2927
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method (View) in the activity class com.example.daniel.proto.Home for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'playButton'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: You forgot to attach icons to your "question". Or, you forgot to try to solve the problem yourself in the first place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you accidentally removed the method from inside the android:onClick of the button.

change:

```
android:onClick=""
```

to:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity, you have a method called onClick(View view). It will be invoked by the click on Button called playButton. But in your xml layout file, you have to mention the method name there in your onClick tag. Otherwise you have to write your listener in your activity something like below:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

and remove that tag :

```
android:onClick=""
```